# include wp custom post templates in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I trying to include two theme template files into a wp plugin that deals with custom post types and for the life of me cant figure out a way to do it, I have searched extensively and believe posting here is the best option if I am to find an answer.

The custom post type is videos which is using single-video.php as the single template and category-253.php for the category and am wanting to move them from the child theme into the plugin/includes/templates directory so the plugin is independent.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

this should cover what you are looking for

http://tommcfarlin.com/page-template-in-plugin/

but as far as plugin integration, you can try the shortcode method to display template codes from plugins

`[myshortcode parm=1 parm=2 parm=3]`

to do something in a plugin like for example list your custom post with different options

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for a simple approach but I will defiantly look into it shortly.

Comment: The plugin example does not work out of the box which is a shame

Comment: define out of the box.. the content?

Comment: the plugin as I understand it is an example plugin with default templates included to show how the templates can be installed into a theme, the example plugin does not work because the example templates do not install.